How can the devil be real?
We Christians say the devil is responsible for our sins and temptations. However, I don't see how this can coexist with scientific knowledge. Specifically, we know that life has adapted over time to surviving and reproducing as much as possible (after all, that is what causes more similar lifeforms to arise - it's called natural selection). This includes hormonal systems in the brain that create a positive response to things like reproduction (sex) or eating (gluttony), along with other behaviors like the challenging of authority, or the seeking of (evil) novelties to carry out, which positively impact the species' prosperity.
However, this also extends to "rational" (non-chemical) sins as well. In the end, every lie, every insult and even every murder comes from an underlying reasoning (in the latter case, it comes from a reasoning which has been heavily corrupted by the conditions in which one has developed, but the point still holds).
Bearing in mind all this, how can we say that there is an external influence "creating" these sins and temptations when it is the internal systems of the brain that are? Saying so would be like saying that demons are responsible for our survival, or like saying that they created these systems in the first place (which, inevitable as they are due to the conditions of the Earth, would imply that they would have created the Earth itself!)
Where does this reasoning go wrong?

There are a lot of assumptions in here. It's puzzling to see how these are suppose to make any claims about ethics at all. The argument you seem to be advancing is that if there is a biological or physical origin for a temptation, there cannot be a metaphysical cause, but that's an assumption at best, borne from an empiricist framework.

Your reasoning goes wrong with your opening sentence and trying to blame hormones on sinful actions merely compounds your fatally flawed thinking. If, as you seem to imply, you are a Christian, then please prove the Christian basis for your claims.

In addition to the previous two comments, it is simply not true that (all) Christians blame evil spirits for all their temptations anx sins, or for all those of non-Christians.  We all have enough evil inside us not to need any prompting from the Evil One or any of his minions. The only one who was not tempted hy his own lusts was our sinless Saviour.  If there is no Devil then He could NOT have been "tempted in all things, just as we are, yet without sin".  He had no sinful human nature, He had the sinless nature, the same as Adam and Eve before they sinned.  So our belief about Christ

About Christ forces us to accept there must be a personal Devil also.  Sometimes sinners are tempted by evil spirits.. but not all our sins are caused by those outside of us.

Your reasoning goes wrong right at the start, by saying "We Christians say that..." Well, proof of that is needed, for none of the Christians I know say that at all! What branch of Christianity, or denomination says what you are claiming? Until that is established, the question is wrong right at the start.
Further, the Protestant (Reformed) Christians I know disagree with the idea that it is "the devil [who] is responsible for our sins and temptations". Contrary to the claim that it is "an external influence "creating" these sins and temptations when it is the internal systems of the brain that are" - Christians can quote many parts in the Bible that show we ourselves have sinful desires that give rise to our succumbing when temptation (opportunities) arise.
Any Christians trying to point the finger of blame for their sins to other people, or to the devil, are deceiving themselves and bringing God's good name into disrepute. To give but two examples of the unpalatable truth the Bible declares about our sinful nature:

"The heart is deceitful above all things, and desperately wicked. Who
can know it? I the Lord search the heart." Jeremiah 17:9 A.V.
"God cannot be tempted with evil, neither tempteth he any man. But
every man is tempted, when he is drawn away of his own lust, and
enticed. Then when lust hath been conceived, it bringeth forth sin:
and sin, when it is finished, bringeth forth death." James 1:13-15
A.V.

One of the roles the devil does play, with regard to sin, is taking the words of God and ever so slightly changing them, or leaving a vital little bit out. Humans who say they are Christians, but who do not know the word of God as they should, or who do not believe all of it, are easy pickings for the devil, whose representatives are quick to whisper wrong ideas about God, and those wrong ideas permeate today's society.

"that ancient serpent who is the devil and Satan" (Revelation). Is the serpent not responsible for tempting Eve? Did he not tempt Christ in the desert? I am surprised that "none of the Christians [you] know say that"! Certainly he is involved in some manner, and certainly he does whatever he can to encourage sin. That said, you are also correct that the ultimate responsibility lies with us, and that we are sinful apart from whatever "extra pushes" Satan might be giving us. To say that he in uninvolved, however, is false.

@Matthew What happened with Eve was just what I said in my answer. Because she did not stick to the exact words of God, the subtle deception presented to her triggered her wrong desire to have that which God said was forbidden. With Christ, he was led by the Spirit to a place where (again) the words of God were twisted, but because he knew the exact word of God and had no desire for what was outside of God's will, he could not be tempted. The role of the devil in both cases proves my point. I answered to refute wrong reasoning by the OP based on belief in evolution without going into that.

Further, I never said that the devil was uninvolved, or that “the devil was not responsible for tempting” Eve or Christ. Eve was responsible for allowing the devil to deceive her. Christ was responsible for refusing to let the devil deceive him.

You said "Christians I know disagree with the idea that it is 'the devil [who] is responsible for our sins and temptations'". Now you say "I never said that the devil [...] was not responsible for tempting". Does that help reveal why I am confused?

@Matthew  It is the OP who claims that the devil is responsible for our temptations. The key phrase that is wrong is, 'responsible for'. No Christian can agree with that, for we are responsible as James 1:13-15 shows. If we did not have sinful lusts, nothing devilish could tempt us, as Jesus proved, refuting subtle lies with "It is written". Yes, the devil is involved with temptations as I said in my last para. showing what role he does play. Yes, he is involved, reading us like a book and knowing our sinful tendencies, be we are responsible. That is the stress in my answer. Sorry if unclear.

@Matthew - are you not misunderstanding Anne's point?  Surely the point is the OP begins by saying "We Christians say the devil is responsible for our sins and temptations". There are two points about this: 1. Does any Christian say the devil is fully responsible for any one of his/her sins?  2. Does not scripture give enough evidence that temptation does not always arise from outside of us, ie from demons outside, but rather arises from our own sinful nature?

@AndrewShanks, Anne's most recent comment is satisfactory. I understand now that Anne is taking issue with the Exact Words (perhaps reasonably), while I was understanding "responsible" to mean "is the source of". I am still not convinced that "is the source of" is an incorrect statement. In the way someone solicited to commit a crime is still culpable for the crime, I agree that Satan's involvement does not absolve us from judgment, but it's not clear that's what the OP intended.

Materialistic theories of how the world both originated and currently operates are reductionistic. Their model of reality posits that everything may be expressed as an arrangement of two forms: matter and energy. There are at least two more forms than these: spirit and information. Spirit cannot be directly measured but information can. Those who subscribe to evolutionary theories believe that information arises spontaneously without a designer:

Manfred Eigen (1927), a Nobel laureate of Göttingen, discusses
questions about life from the molecular biology view, with as point of
departure the unwarranted postulate that natural laws controlled the
origin of life. In his work on the self-organization of matter, he
uses an impressive array of formulas, but does not rise above the
level of statistical information. This voluminous work is thus useless
and does not answer any questions about the origin of information and
of life. He writes, “Information arises from non-information.”
This statement is nothing but a confession of materialism, and it
fails the tests required by reality.

(Quoted from https://answersingenesis.org/genetics/information-theory/information-in-living-organisms/ )
The information content of organisms has been measured, being stored in our DNA as a code of four letters, A, T, G, and C (for Adenosine, Tyrosine, Guanine and Cytosine). Rates of mutation have been measured in the laboratory. The time required for random mutations to create the full information content of a human - or even the simplest microorganism - exceeds by an incredible amount the age of the universe, even if you concede that it is 20 billion years old or so. The information was put there by a designer. Even though information of that kind is immaterial, it rules everything.
(The computations comparing mutation rate to DNA information content are in an article on the AIG website that I read years ago. If I find it, I will post a link.)
Since information is a fundamental property of life, anything that tampers with information is dangerous. The serpent as a servant or incarnation of Satan tempted Eve through a corruption of information that we call a lie. He operates on principles related to a substance - information - whose fundamental existence as an independent component of nature is denied by science. That is why science as currently conducted cannot be reconciled with the existence of the devil. His substance is invisible to them because they refuse to see it.


I don't see how [existence of the Devil] can coexist with scientific knowledge.

If you define "science" as the a priori rejection of the supernatural, then it can't, of course. The better question to ask is whether this approach to "science" is valid. To that end, the questions "does God exist?", "is Scripture true?", "was Jesus" (who historians almost unanimously agree existed) "really raised from the dead?". If your answer to any of the above is "yes", then Jesus (who is God incarnate) and Scripture (which is God's Word) both state unequivocally that evil, supernatural forces exists. They also, collectively, make many claims that contradict the findings of "science"... but remember that those findings are ultimately based in a false world view which takes "there is no supernatural" as an axiom and cannot help but come to wrong conclusions for any event that involved a miracle (such as Creation).
If your answer to all of the above is "no", then you are not Christian, and why do you care whether the Devil exists?

We know that life has adapted over time to surviving and reproducing as much as possible.

This, as you wrote it, is true. However, the way you are using this argument suggests that you believe (as "science" claims) that Natural Selection turned pond scum into people. This is false; it is explicitly denied by Scripture (which teaches that humans were a unique and special act of Creation), and there are many problems with this belief, to the extent that many scientists, even ones not necessarily Christian, believe it is incorrect. Moreover, while it is generally agreed that the body has some influence on the mind, Scripture is clear that men (that is, humans), being in part spirit, are intended to master the body rather than be controlled by it.

In the end, every lie, every insult and even every murder comes from an underlying reasoning. [In some cases], from a reasoning which has been heavily corrupted by the conditions in which one has developed.

There is much truth in this. Adam and Eve were Created without sin, but once they did that which was forbidden, sin pervaded all of Creation, including human nature. No one born in this world is innocent; our every desire has been corrupted by sin until there is no good in us. Given your Question, it may surprise you that I'm agreeing with you on this point! So, let's keep going...

How can we say that there is an external influence "creating" these sins and temptations?

We don't! Not always. The propensity to sin is inherent in human nature, and the consequences permeate all of Creation. What is true is a) that sin entered the world through the Fall, which is traced back to "the serpent"  (usually believed to be the same entity as "the Devil" / "Satan"), and b) that we believe there are evil forces ("demons") which encourage people to sin. I don't know that I would call that "creating" sin, however. The propensity is already present in this world, introduced perhaps by the Devil, but his role now is more that of cheer-leader and sometimes just spectator.

Saying so would be like saying that demons [...] created these systems in the first place (which, inevitable as they are due to the conditions of the Earth, would imply that they would have created the Earth itself!).

Demons did not Create Earth. Again, demonic forces ("the serpent", which at minimum would be a specific demon and not "demons" as a category) introduced sin into the world via the original temptation in Eden, thereby corrupting human nature and in that sense being (indirectly) responsible for the resulting Curse on nature. But God Created everything.
Another issue seems to be that you believe e.g. hormonal responses to be evil in and of themselves. This is incorrect. It isn't evil in and of itself that we find eating or procreating to be pleasurable; in fact, God made it so for our good. It is through a combination of the corruption of the world resulting from sin, failure to exercise the self-control that God intends and desires, and perhaps demonic influences, that our bodies can master our minds. Thus, again, it is not demons that originated these things; rather, what was originally Created Very Good has been corrupted.

But animals, for example, have very similar kinds of behaviors (excluding the more complex rational ones, of course). How could they have originated with the Fall?

@Flamethrower, the Fall affected all of Creation (n.b. Genesis 3:15,17,18, Romans 8:22).

Actually, your first statement is not true to my Orthodox understanding. And as always, short version at the bottom. :)
First of all, the word translated to "temptation" is "peirasmos, peirazō" (I will bold these words in the english translations below)
3 things can be involved in temptation. God, the Devil, and each of us personally.

Matthew 4:1 "Then Jesus was led up by the Spirit into the wilderness to be tempted by the devil"

So, God did not directly tempt but did lead Jesus to a place where he would undergo temptation from the devil.

Luke 4:13 "Now when the devil had ended every temptation, he departed from Him until an opportune time."

In this case, it is very clear the temptation is from the devil. However the word is also used in another way.

Hebrews 11:17 " By faith Abraham, when he was tested, offered up Isaac, and he who had received the promises offered up his only begotten son"

Notice that God tested Abraham. Tests of faith come from God.
There are other verses show God's involvement with temptation. Such as 1st Cor 10:13 where God does not allow us to be tempted beyond what we can withstand or 2 peter 2:9 where God is the one who rescues us from temptation. Additionally the Lord's prayer and Revelation 3:10 teach that God is able to keep us from a time of testing.
Finally there is the matter of the human involved. 1 Tim 6:9, James 1:2, James 1:13-14, and other verses all show that it is human desires that bring temptations such as wealth, and it is not God that is pulling us toward the darkness.

So now that the theological base is clear. I believe we can see where the reasoning is going awry.

You are seeking a scientific proof for a spiritual force. We cannot "prove" God within science, there is no reason to expect us to "prove the devil" within the boundaries of science either.


Scientists will tell you that demons don’t exist because they cannot test for them. They are not material objects and cannot be observed, because they are spirits. We often forget that there is not simply the world that can be examined, touched, and observed; there is also the spiritual realm that cannot be examined with the eyes, but only with a discerning heart. -Fr. James Guirguis

Now here is an interesting point to consider in the modern age... if you were a spiritual power, able to suggest things to humans and even to directly do things that could be proven... why would you unless you knew they wouldn't ever be believed or that they were so entrenched in their Faith that only a direct attack would possibly succeed?
When they say the greatest accomplishment the devil ever performed was "convincing the world he didn't exist" there aren't exactly wrong. Even with my mortal intellect (which I will admit is significantly weaker than that of demons and angels!) I wouldn't give proof that I existed.
... We could go into great length now, about how to possibly identify a demon. I actually have a good example, that I will censor to protect the guilty and to be polite.

Imagine someone tells you about a beautiful divine vision of God and Jesus. And about their message, and about an angel that has been sent to guide them to reform the church, because the church on earth has been lost and corrupted.
Or perhaps your great grandparent tells the story about someone who used to predict the future with accuracy. Telling of the results of battles around the world, of the weather that would come next week, of the plots to assassinate important figures.
Both of these examples have clear lies within them from the "divine". The angel and vision are false because they claimed something that contradicts scripture and God's own promises. Yet people still believe them by the thousands.
The "predictions" are not of the future they are just in real time with the intellect of thousands of years of evil behind them. A demon can travel faster than anything we know (not bound by physics), can observe everything, can use thousands of years of experience and their entire intellect against your naive few decades. But of course humans were tricked by the hundreds.

Short version:
God tests us. God allows us to be tempted, but not beyond our limit. God saves us from temptation if we ask. God leads us to tests of faith, because these tests give us good fruits.
Our sinful nature after the fall affects us. We routinely will give in to simple temptations both primal and rational. Both rational or not.
The devil and the demons, are very real but cannot be proven by science. They are not responsible for our sins those are our own actions, demons and the devil they will tempt us to sin, to make us weak, to steal us from God.
The reasoning breaks immediately in your train of thought, because you are attempting to prove something that is not possible to test for and is not bound by natural laws.

What do you mean it's not possible to explain temptation with science? Precisely what I don't understand is how hormonal temptations (and their origins and evolutionary causes) and the devil can coexist in belief.

@Flamethrower, if your friend urges you to buy something, and you give in... you only gave in because of your hormones, right? I think it's obvious that's nonsense. Behavioral influences take many forms and can complement or contradict one another. If you believe only chemicals can affect behavior, then logically you must also reject free will as an illusion. Do you reject free will?

But those "chemical" temptations and free will are different things. Free will is not instinct, it's reason. Reason also plays a part in many cases, but it still comes from factors developed over time.

@Flamethrower I didn't say we couldn't explain temptation with science. I said we cannot prove spiritual forces like God, Satan, Demons, Angels, etc. with science. You specifically say "chemical" and "free will" temptations are different things... so you literally have given yourself an answer. Chemical ones I guess are fixed, and the devil goes after your free will.
